# PageIndexChanging error

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am using Paging in my code and it throws error "The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled."

Following is my code (only the relevant part):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" 
              OnPageIndexChanging="SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging">
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select DB_monitor.name, 
DB_monitor.priority, DB_alert.creationtime, DB_message.message from DB_alert
INNER JOIN DB_monitor on DB_alert.monitor = DB_monitor.ID
INNER JOIN DB_message on DB_alert.errmess = DB_message.ID
where DB_monitor.application = @strApplication and DB_monitor.instance = 
@strInstances and DB_monitor.priority = @Priority and
DB_alert.creationtime between @FromDate and @ToDate and DB_alert.errmess != '1'"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@strApplication", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);// Set SqlDbType based on your DB column Data-Type
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@strInstances", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Priority", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
            cmd.Parameters["@strApplication"].Value = ddlApplication.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters["@strInstances"].Value = ddlInstances.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters["@Priority"].Value = ddlPriority.SelectedValue;
            //2017-04-01 00:00:00.000
            cmd.Parameters["@FromDate"].Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
            cmd.Parameters["@ToDate"].Value = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");


            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
} // [Edit: sic!]
}
```

Comment: And where have you defined your SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging method in your code? If not you have to create a method in code behind.

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya Hi Mukesh. How do I go ahead after removing OnPageIndexChanging="SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging?

Comment: You need to implement in code behind the event handler, but if you want to go ahead without implementing right now, remove that it will work! Just check and let me know if it is working.

Comment: I removed it and the code works. But when I click on the page number, the PageIndexing error occurs. If you can let me know how to implement in code behind the event handler it would be great.

Comment: Added sample implementation in answer. And why have you return code to get data for grid in button submit?

Comment: Only now I have added the PageIndexing, the code was previously getting over ater clicking the submit button. I am unsure of how to separate the code for submit and PageIndex event since, the data fills from DB and I am using cmd in Submit button.

Comment: create method using your code in button click, I am updating the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi Aarthi, Do some changes in your code :-**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGridView();
}
protected void SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging(objectsender,GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGridView();
}
protected void BindGridView()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select DB_monitor.name, 
                DB_monitor.priority, DB_alert.creationtime, DB_message.message from DB_alert
                INNER JOIN DB_monitor on DB_alert.monitor = DB_monitor.ID
                INNER JOIN DB_message on DB_alert.errmess = DB_message.ID
                where DB_monitor.application = @strApplication and DB_monitor.instance = 
                @strInstances and DB_monitor.priority = @Priority and
                DB_alert.creationtime between @FromDate and @ToDate and DB_alert.errmess != '1'"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@strApplication", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);// Set SqlDbType based on your DB column Data-Type
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@strInstances", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Priority", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
            cmd.Parameters["@strApplication"].Value = ddlApplication.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters["@strInstances"].Value = ddlInstances.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters["@Priority"].Value = ddlPriority.SelectedValue;
            //2017-04-01 00:00:00.000
            cmd.Parameters["@FromDate"].Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
            cmd.Parameters["@ToDate"].Value = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");


            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a breeze. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

You have just declared Page index changing event in your aspx as OnPageIndexChanging="SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging" but have not defined same in your code behind

Just define event handler something like below in your code behind page

```
protected void GridView1_SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = getGridData(); //get datasource for your grid in that method
    GridView1.DataBind(); //bind the data
}
```

Find more at [GridView.PageIndexChanging Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging(v=vs.110).aspx)

And implement your getGridData() method using the code for fetching the data that written in button click and return data table so that will be assigned to Gridview's datasource.

```
public DataTable getGridData()
{
  string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select DB_monitor.name, 
            DB_monitor.priority, DB_alert.creationtime, DB_message.message from DB_alert
            INNER JOIN DB_monitor on DB_alert.monitor = DB_monitor.ID
            INNER JOIN DB_message on DB_alert.errmess = DB_message.ID
            where DB_monitor.application = @strApplication and DB_monitor.instance = 
            @strInstances and DB_monitor.priority = @Priority and
            DB_alert.creationtime between @FromDate and @ToDate and DB_alert.errmess != '1'"))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@strApplication", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);// Set SqlDbType based on your DB column Data-Type
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@strInstances", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Priority", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters["@strApplication"].Value = ddlApplication.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters["@strInstances"].Value = ddlInstances.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters["@Priority"].Value = ddlPriority.SelectedValue;
        //2017-04-01 00:00:00.000
        cmd.Parameters["@FromDate"].Value = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
        cmd.Parameters["@ToDate"].Value = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");


        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: what do I change in the Submit button code when accomodating the code given by you?

Comment: On submit, the query fetches  data from DB and fills the grid. That is why using cmd in Submit button. But if i remove it, it gives me error.

Comment: you can assign data source in Page_Load, using GridView1.DataSource = getGridData(); GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Or if you are supposed to fill grid on button click only then you can add GridView1.DataSource = getGridData(); GridView1.DataBind(); in your button click.