# HTML ExportToExcel Button

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an ExportToExcel button in my application which is seen all the time. I want this to be changed to be shown only after I click submit and the result is shown.
Here is the code:

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export To Excel" OnClick = "ExportToExcel" />
```

```cs
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "text/xls";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=HistoricalReporting.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        //To Export all pages
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        this.BindGridView();

        GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                cell.CssClass = "textmode";
            }
        }

        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}
```

Comment: So? Seems pretty straight forward. Make the button start invisible. Handle your submit button's click event and make the button visible. Have you tried anything, or do you just want us to write all the code for you?

Comment: You might want to consider accepting some of your other questions as answered too e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535587/pageindexchanging-error
Generally, you will get more responses when you mark questions as answered.